# Django is rendering an awkward result

Tags: python, django, django-models

Basically, I am working on a django project, and whenever I insert data into the database, the result is weirdly formatted.

this is my model

customer.py

```
    class Customer(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        email= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        phone_number= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
      
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Now, say I have saved a new customer

```
    new_customer =   Customer.objects.create(name="Henry",email="henry@mail.com",phone_number="+330145786259")
    new_customer.save()
```

when i try to retrieve the customer name i get this:

```
    print(new_customer.name)
    >('henry',)
```

Anyone has any insight for me???

I tried to recreate the model on a new project but still having the same result

Comment: Are you _sure_ there isn't a call to `.lower()` somewhere in the codebase? If you INSERT / UPDATE a mixed case name, does that work? What does SELECT report? [Tell us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which RDBMS you're using as the backend.

Comment: no, there is no  `.lower()` in the code base.. I am using sqlite3

Comment: We have sqlite and python in the mix. There are four combinations: (1.) sqlite INSERT, sqlite SELECT, (2.) sqlite INSERT, python read, (3.) python write, sqlite SELECT, (4.) python write, python read. You reported on scenario 4. Please tell us about the other three combinations. What do you observe? Also, is the name corrupted immediately after the create()? or only after the save() that you showed? or only after reading new_customer from sqlite? Your overall symptom is "impossible", yet it happens, so we need to proceed in tiny baby steps, being suspicious, checking everything.

Comment: Why is `new.customer_name` returning a _tuple_ (`('henry',)`)?

Comment: I am using Django ORM so I am not dealing with SQL syntax

Answer (score 0):

In your customer class, you have defined a 1:1 relationship with the in-built user model class of django. And when you are creating the customer object, *new_customer*, you have not specified the 'user' attribute; hence, your customer object is missing a key element.

The user object already has an in-built field for storing names. It is 'first_name' and 'last_name.' You need to create a user model first before being able to create your 'Customer' model.

Your models.py should look something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
        # to return email -> self.user.email
```

Now to create a 'Customer' object in view.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Customer

# create a user object
myuser = User.objects.create_user(username='john', email='jlennon@beatles.com', password='glass onion')
# pass the user object to the customer model 
mycustomer = Customer.objects.create(user=myuser, phone_number=123456789)
# save the customer object
mycustomer.save()
```

Explore django [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) to define the user model as per your specifications, e.g, if you don't require your users to have passwords associated with them, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Malik, I tried it but it didn't work. The user field can be null, I did this on purpose... Plus this has never caused me any trouble up to now.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the format of the data in the admin panel? Is it shown in the appropriate format there?

Comment: Yes, I have... It gives the same format in the admin panel

Answer (score 0):

After much testing, I realized why I was getting the weird output.
I was directly passing data from a form to the object creation method, like so:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
new_customer = Customer.objects.create(name=data['name'],email="henry@mail.com",phone_number="+330145786259")
new_customer.save()
```

So assigning the received data to a variable before passing it to the object creation method seems to be the right way of doing things... At least, it is working for me.